# How to read NodeMCU GPIO pin status?

Tags: esp8266, pins, c, nodemcu

I am setting up a page on NodeMCU running as a web server and I want to be able to turn on and off a light based on the url being clicked.

I want to know how I can get the status so that I can set the URL based on the pin status as well as pass  the GPIO pin status in the JSON from the NodeMCU web server.

The code is [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36330/how-to-make-5volt-relay-to-work-with-node-mcu?noredirect=1#comment72314_36330).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independent of the setting of port direction (input or output), pin can be read through the digitalRead():

```
int pin_light = 3;
int status = digitalRead(pin_light);
```

Comment: The OP said he has a NodeMCU board. Those runs Lua code. Your example seems to be C-code and would not work on a NodeMCU unless you "reflash" it to standard Arduino C-code. Reading a pin on NodeMCU should be gpio.read(PIN)

Comment: The OP said he has a NodeMCU board. Those runs Lua code. Your example seems to be C-code and would not work on a NodeMCU unless you "reflash" it to standard Arduino C-code. Reading a pin on NodeMCU should be gpio.read(PIN)

Comment: You are rigth, but question refers an example with code and C and it is tagged with C :blink: